# Validate Location Coordinates in Android EditText

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext, geolocation

I want to get the location coordinates from the user through EditText, I decide to set the input type as decimal but location coordinates come with a minus(-), for that, I want to validate the coordinates, How can I do that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String lati=edlat.getText().toString().trim();
String longi=edlng.getText().toString().trim();

if(isNumber(lati)&&isNumber(longi)&&isValidLatLng(Double.valueOf(lati),Double.valueOf(longi)))
{
   // your logic
}

public boolean isValidLatLng(double lat, double lng){
        if(lat < -90 || lat > 90)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Latitude", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        else if(lng < -180 || lng > 180)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Longitude", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isNumber(String str) {
        try {
            double v = Double.parseDouble(str);
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            Toast.makeText(ShopDetails.this, ""+nfe.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }
```